# SimpleGUICS2Pygame Installing on Linux

Tags: python, linux, codeskulptor

Python.

I've exhausted my research on this topic. I have it running on Windows just fine, but I can't figure out a way to install it on Linux.

How do I install it on Linux?

Answer (score 1):

The installation guide is [here](http://simpleguics2pygame.readthedocs.org/). I installed it 10 Minutes ago on Ubuntu(13.10) using the following command:

```
sudo pip install SimpleGUICS2Pygame
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an ordinary python package, so just:

`pip install --user SimpleGUICS2Pygame`

If that gives errors, post them.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is:

```
python -m pip install SimpleGUICS2Pygame --user --upgrade
```

Since the version 2 all requirements are automatically installed. But for that you need have Python tools up to date. All steps are described in the online documentation:
https://simpleguics2pygame.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#installation